# Inner join to fetch columns from a look up table pandas

Tags: join, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one data frame has following structure

```
property art_size date measurements values
```

second dataframe has following structure:

```
property destination businessgroup business
```

I want to get the values of destination businessgroup and business for each of the property values in the first dataframe. So, the resultant dataframe should be :

```
destination businessgroup business property art_size data measurement values
```

I used merge function , to do this :

```
pd.merge(first_df, second_df, how = 'inner' , left_on=['property'], right_on=['property'])
```

first_df has 46 K rows and second_df ahs 56 K rows. but the resultant I got has 18 million records( so a cross join has happened). Any idea where I am going wrong? I was expecting it will have only 46 K rows with 3 more columns(destination, businessgroup, business) having values corresponding to the property value in that row

Comment: Could you make a small example that reproduces the problem?  ([mcve])

Comment: @DSM, I will try to come up with an example. Here, join is not happening the way I want, any reason you can think of  as to why this is gng wrong?

Comment: @DSM : I figured the problem, the dfs which I was taking had multiple rows for each of the properties and hence the no of rows were a lot more..I made sure that the dataframe has unique combinations of rows before joining